# Access Spring Boot Application JAR in Standandalone Java Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, executable-jar

I have a Spring Boot Application with REST Controller class having two REST endpoints

I want to package it to a JAR and access the REST endpoint methods as normal method invocation in a Standalone java class

I have added the JAR in my project build bath as shown below:

[image]

I am unable to create an Object for the Rest Controller class in my Standalone project despite adding JAR in class path

For ex: I have a class called TestController and a method called testMethod() that is mapped to (/test) path.

Instead of invoking it as HTTP endpoint, I want to create Object for the controller class and access method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestController test = new TestController();
    test.testMethod();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the uber-jar that spring boot creates is not intended to be used as a dependency. As it includes a custom classloader and the dependent jars within a lib directory. The standard java classloader can't load classes from there. Your options are to extract the rest controllers (or all classes that you want to re-use) into a maven module and use the resulting jar as a dependency in both your spring boot application and the other app you cant to create around it. Another approach would be to expose the services the rest controller uses and have a less "RESTy" dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin to build two artifacts: one as a normal 'library' jar, containing only the classes of your project, and one as fat, executable jar. See [spring-boot-maven-plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#repackage-examples)

With a default spring-boot-project, having spring-boot-starter-parent as parent, the configuration below will generate a normal `<artifactId>-<version>.jar` and a fat `<artifactId>-<version>-exec.jar`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Without the spring-boot-starter-parent it requires a slightly different configuration - see the referenced docs.